# Boundary of the set in function space

Tags: functional-analysis

I don't have any idea how to understand $C^4$ (4th differentiable and continuous function space)  topology well.

One of the paper said, 
Suppose that $w(x)$ satisfies $w(0)=c$, $w'(0)<0$, $w''(0)=0$,and $w'''(0)>0$.
Then all the functions $v(x)$ satisfying $w(0)=c$, $w'(0)<0$, $w''(0)=0$, $w'''(0)=0$, $w^{(n)}(0)>0$ for some n>3 is placed on the boundary of the set of $w$ in $C^4$ topology.

I don't know how to understand it, and why it is true.
If you know, please help me:)

Comment: What is your topology on $C^{4}$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry, the paper just mentioned it as 'For a suitable topology,...' and I'm not familiar with topology. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you at least know what the domain of these functions is?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, it is just the real line space. 1 dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not know what the topology is I will assume that it is the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets of the functions and their first four derivatives. This is a fairly standard topology. Consider the sequences $(v(x)+\frac {x^{3}} n)$ and  $(v(x)-\frac {x^{3}} n)$. These two sequences both converge to $v$. One sequence is inside the given set and the other is outside. This proves that $v$ is on the boundary of the set.

Comment: Thank you! I think I need more time to understand your answer fully, but it is really helpful.:)